# Electron, internal packages and testing

Tags: javascript, electron

I m actually building an application using electron and I m having some troubles dealing with packages that are built in electron.

I have a test that look like following using chai mocha an:

```
it('should call the remote#hideWindow method', () => {

            /**
             * Mock definition
             */
            mock.expects('getCurrentWindow').returns({
                hide: () => {
                    // Do some job
                }
            });

            const spy = chai.spy(remote.getCurrentWindow().hide);

            /**
             * Real test case
             */
            const googleSearchBar = new GoogleSearchBar(document.getElementById('search'));
            googleSearchBar.hideWindow();
            expect(spy).to.have.been.called();
        });
```

My problem is that I can't use the 'remote' package using :

```
const remote = require('remote');
```

In fact, I can require('remote') inside of my app, the one running on the browser, but not in my test. And I don't know how to do make it accessible inside of my test file.

Can you help me ?

EDIT : The same thing happens when I try to use Web API such as notifications or webspeechrecognition. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you're actually running these tests, they have to be run in an Electron process not a regular Node process. I'd suggest looking at [Spectron](https://github.com/electron/spectron).

Comment: What if my app hasn't an executable yet ? Spectron asks for an executable path that I dont have during dev time

Comment: @Skahrz If your app isn't packaged then you'd use the `electron` executable, which is exactly what the tests for Spectron do: https://github.com/electron/spectron/blob/v3.1.0/test/global-setup.js#L26